# Concat async observable data based on click event

Tags: angular, event-handling, observable

My page display a list of opportunities based on web service,
after that, i want to load more opportunities after clicking on the "`Load More`" button, which i couldn't find the best way to keep the same observable '`opportunities`'

this is my code source :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {  Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Opportunity } from "../../models/opportunity.model";
import { OpportunityService } from "../../services/opportunity.service";

@Component({

template : `
<div class="container-lg">
        <mat-toolbar><span i18n>Opportunities</span></mat-toolbar>
        <app-cards *ngIf="opportunities$ | async as opportunities; else searchLoading" [opportunities]="opportunities"></app-cards>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="loadOportunities()" color="primary">Load More</button>

        <ng-template #searchLoading>
          <div class="center"><mat-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner></div>
        </ng-template>
      </div>




`,
styleUrls : ['opportunities.page.scss']


})

export class OpportunitiesPage implements OnInit {



  offset: number = 0;
  limit: number = 12;

  opportunities$?: Observable<Opportunity[]> ;

  constructor(private opportunityService : OpportunityService){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.opportunities$ = this.opportunityService.getSeacrhOpportunities(this.offset , this.limit);

  }

  loadOportunities(): void{
    this.offset =  this.offset+this.limit;
    //TODO concat newest with oldest opportunities
}
}
```

for the opportunity service :

```
 getSeacrhOpportunities(offset: number , limit : number): Observable<Opportunity[]> {
          let param: any = {'offset': offset , 'limit' : limit , 'locale' : this.locale};
          return this.httpClient.get<APIData<Opportunity[]>>(`${environment.apiUrl}/ws/opportunities`, {params: param}).pipe(
            map((response) => response.data),
            catchOffline(),
          );

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the offset and limit in a `BehaviorSubject` and then pipe (listen) for changes in that variable

```
export class OpportunitiesPage {
  load$ = new BehaviorSubject<{ offset: number; limit: number }>({
    limit: 12,
    offset: 0,
  });

  opportunities$ = this.load$.pipe(
    map((x) => this.opportunityService.getSeacrhOpportunities(x.offset, x.limit))
  );

  constructor(private opportunityService: OpportunityService) {}

  loadOportunities(): void {
    // just setting some values dont know what you want to happend
    this.load$.next({ limit: 10, offset: 10 });
  }
}
```

In this case the type will result in a `Observable<Observable<Opportunity[]>>`, we dont want that and that can be resolves using `switchMap` over `map` resulting in the type `Observable<Opportunity[]>`

```
  //will be of type Observable<Opportunity[]>
  opportunities$ = this.load$.pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.getSeacrhOpportunities(x.limit, x.offset))
  )
```

Then just access it as usual

html:

```
<div *ngif="opportunities$ | async as opportunities"></div>
```

Comment: getSeacrhOpportunities(offset: number , limit : number): Observable<Opportunity[]>

so opportunities$ will be an Observable<Observable<Opportunity[]>>
is that fine or no ?

Comment: Correct, that can cause some issues, but then you should be able to use a switchmap instead of only map

Comment: while getSeacrhOpportunities() return an Observable<Opportunity[]>

the opportunities$ will be of type Observable<Observable<Opportunity[]>>

or should i change the way* i retrieve data ?

Comment: @Mirlo Updated the snippet

Comment: I believe the author wants to concatenate subsequent results, this will just show the new results.

Comment: your solution seems logical, but after clicking on the button,  the WS is never called !

Comment: Good solution, concatenation can be achieved using the `scan` operator ie: `concatenated$ = opportunities$.pipe((acc,curr) => acc.concat(curr));` then subscribe to `concatenated$` in your template using `async` pipe and avoiding manual subscribe

Comment: concatenated$ = this.opportunities$.pipe((acc,curr) => acc.concat(curr));
could not working cause opportunities$ is type of Observable<Opportunity[]>

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to append old and new data, you should use a variable to store your data instead of using an async pipe in the html. We can use a variable to indicate loading as well.

```js
  offset: number = 0;
  limit: number = 12;

  opportunities: Opportunity[] = [];

  loading = true;

  constructor(private opportunityService: OpportunityService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadOportunities();
  }

  loadOportunities(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.opportunityService
      .getSeacrhOpportunities(this.offset, this.limit)
      .subscribe((newOpps) => {
        this.opportunities = this.opportunities.concat(newOpps);
        this.loading = false;
      });
    this.offset += this.limit;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-lg">
  <mat-toolbar><span i18n>Opportunities</span></mat-toolbar>
  <app-cards [opportunities]="opportunities"></app-cards>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="loadOportunities()" color="primary">
    Load More
  </button>

  <ng-container *ngIf="loading">
    <div class="center">
      <mat-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

I would have the progress spinner appear underneath or floating on top.

**Making the subscription more robust**

To make this more robust, you can prevent the user from making multiple parallel requests, and only increment the offset if the subscription is successful. You can also add error handling, and set loading to false when the subscription completes, successfully or unsuccessfully.

```js
  loadOportunities(): void {
    if (this.loading) return;
    this.loading = true;
    this.opportunityService
      .getSeacrhOpportunities(this.offset, this.limit)
      .subscribe({
        next: (newOpps) => {
          this.opportunities = this.opportunities.concat(newOpps);
          this.offset += this.limit;
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          //Error handling
        },
        complete: () => (this.loading = false),
      });
  }
```

It's not necessary to unsubscribe here. See this question to learn more: [Angular/RxJS When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38008334/12914833)

If ever you want to cancel a request you can use `unsubscribe()` to do so.

Comment: your solution works but the offset is never incremented !

Comment: I noticed that bug, I updated the code. I initially declared the observable in `ngOnInit` which attached the numbers themselves rather than a reference to the variables.

Comment: Thanks Chris, your solution works correctly, 
on this way each click generate a subscription, is that normal ?
or should i unsubscribe after the finish of the event ?

Comment: It's not necessary to unsubscribe when it comes to http requests, since the subscriptions will be cleaned up after a single response. You can however unsubscribe in order to cancel a request. I agree it's dangerous to let the user create multiple requests at a time, so you may want to disable the button when `loading` is true.

Comment: I've edited my answer for more info.